# Двоеточие, запятая или вообще ничего?

Tags: пунктуация, знак

Есть предложение: "Суточная норма хлеба для человека(: *или* ,) не склонного к полноте - 100-150 г, для склонного к полноте - 30-60 г".
Какой знак препинания здесь употребить правильнее?

Answer (score 1):

Распространенное определение "не склонного к полноте" стоит после определяемого слова "человека", поэтому обособляется: Суточная норма хлеба для человека, не склонного к полноте, - 100-150 г, для склонного к полноте - 30-60 г.

Answer (score 0):

А почему здесь ставится тире перед цифрами? Потому что пропущено слово "равна"? Или есть другие причины?

Comment: Вы правы: тире заменяет собой отсутствующее слово в неполном предложении

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложила такое оформление:

Суточная норма хлеба для человека: не склонного к полноте - 100-150 г,  склонного к полноте - 30-60 г.

Кстати, постановка двоеточия АВТОРСКАЯ и  зависит от стиля текста и особенностей его оформления. Если это то место в специальной литературе, где приводятся справочные данные, то двоеточие желательно - оно заменяет пропущенное обобщающее слово "следующая" и здесь делается предупреждающая пауза.

Другой вариант: Суточная норма хлеба для не склонного к полноте человека -  100-150 г, для склонного к полноте - 30-60 г.

Все-таки желательно, чтобы знаков препинания в тексте было меньше, но при этом они должны ясно раскрывать содержание текста.

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие раскрывает, поясняет следующее за ним предложение. В данном случае нет никаких пояснительных отношений, поэтому, как отметил Виктор, нужно поставить запятую.

Comment: Дорогой Серж! Уже не первый раз Вы умиляете меня своей деликатностью и стремлением соблюдать "авторские права", не выдавая ответ коллеги за свой, а просто поддерживая то, что до Вас уже написано. Такая порядочность дорогого стОит. Спасибо за поддержку. С Новым годом Вас, юный друг!

Comment: Спасибо! И вас так же!